# May one daven Shemona Esrai in a regular (rather than low) voice, if one is davening by oneself and there's no one around you to distract or disturb?

Tags: tefilla

Shalom--Can one daven Shemonah Esrai in a regular (rather than whispering voice) if one is davening alone at home and there's no one to distract or disturb?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73551/can-i-say-the-amidah-out-loud-if-it-helps-my-kavanah dupe of  dupe

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11336/3483